# AngularJS: format the 5 or 9 digit zip-code with dash

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, filter, format

There is a string expression `{{zipcode}}` that displays 5 or 9 digit number.

What's the best way to display this zip-code in `xxxxx` or `xxxxx-xxxx` format automatically?

I believe using filter is the way to go, but slightly confused with filter and ui-mask.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using filters is indeed the solution for this. Here are two solutions:

### Use a module

You can add [angular-zipcode-filter](https://github.com/felippenardi/angular-zipcode-filter) in your project and format zip code using this filter:

`{{ 981222735 | zipcode }}`

### Do it yourself

Here is how this filter works:

1. Receives an input
2. Verifies that it has 5 or 9 digits
3. Returns a formatted zipcode output if it has 9 digits
4. Leave it as is in case it has 5 digits

Example:

```js
angular.module('myApp',[])
  .filter('zipcode', function () {
    return function (input) {
      if (!input) {
        return input;
      }
      if (input.toString().length === 9) {
        return input.toString().slice(0, 5) + "-" + input.toString().slice(5);
      } else if (input.toString().length === 5) {
        return input.toString();
      } else {
        return input;
      }
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <p>5-digit zip code: {{ 981222735 | zipcode }} </p>
  <p>9-digit zip code: {{ 98122 | zipcode }} </p>
</div>
```